# What is the remainder when $P(x)$ is divided by $x^2-2x-35$?

Tags: polynomials

Question: 
When $P(x)$ is divided by $x-7$, the remainder is $11$.
When $P(x)$ is divided by $x+5$, the remainder is $-3$. 
What is the remainder when $P(x)$ is divided by $x^2-2x-35$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

The remainder of $P(x)$ divided by $x^2-2x-35=(x-7)(x+5)$ is of the form $ax+b.$ That is:

$$P(x)=(x^2-2x-35)Q(x)+ax+b.$$

Now, using that $P(7)=11$ and $P(-5)=-3$ we can get $a,b.$